# htaccess redirect if index.php is missing

Tags: .htaccess

Sorry, I tried everything but cannot get it to run. Any help very appreciated.
I need a very basic staging-system. Everything works fine, but the following **.htaccess** isn't working...:

---

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^dev.
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !DEVELOPMENT/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/DEVELOPMENT/index.(html|php) !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !../maintenance/maintenance.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../maintenance/maintenance.html [R=307]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^dev.

ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !DEVELOPMENT/

ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ DEVELOPMENT/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^dev.
[.... same code - different directory: /TESTING]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^www.
[.... same code - different directory: /PRODUCTION]
`

---

**The structure:**

- root

  - .htaccess
  - DEVELOPMENT (directory)

    - index.php
  - TESTING (directory)

    - index.php
  - PRODUCTION (directory)

    - index.php
  - MAINTENANCE (directory)

    - maintenance.html

**Not working:**

- if "index.php" is missing, a Site is displayed: Title "307 Temporary Redirect" - Content: Temporary Redirect - The document has moved here(link to the same site: iE dev.example.com)

**My purpose:**

- redirect every request to the right folder (dev.example.com -> /DEVELOPMENT)
- if file "/DEVELOPMENT/index.php" OR Folder "DEVELOPMENT" is missing -> redirect to "/MAINTENANCE/maintenance.html"
- same for "/TESTING" and "/PRODUCTION"
- use one .htacess for the whole enviroment (dev.example.com -> /DEVELOPMENT // test.example.com -> /TESTING // www.example.com -> /PRODUCTION)
- let Google know, it's only temporary for site updates

Hope, i explained my problem clearly...
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You say you want to put all the logic in one .htaccess for the whole environment, Is there a reason? I would suggest it would be simpler to setup and maintain in 3 virtual host configurations (one per environment).

Comment: yes, i need to use htaccess because with some clients it's hard to setup virtual host configurations - and easier to shift domains/directories.